# two query results in 1 $variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to use codeigniter activerecords to pull some records from two tables that have the same structure.  For example I have a MARKET table with two fields (name, name_spanish) and I have an APPLICATION table with the same two fields (name, name_spanish).

Can I create a `$data` variable and put the results of each query into it?  Then I'd want to check the results like this psuedocode `$spanish = $data['name_spanish'] where $data['name'] = "Hello"`

Can this be accomplished?

Comment: Is your pseudocode supposed to be a SQL query?

Comment: I'm confused, what are you trying to do?

Comment: it looks like he wants to load two tables into an english->spanish dictionary, but i am just guessing.  $dictionary['hello'] => 'hola'

Comment: Sorry the psuedocode is suppose to be php logic :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a *UNION* query.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE foo = 1 
  UNION SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE bar = 3 AND baz = 3
```

I don't think CodeIgniter's ActiveRecord supports union queries, so [use the `query` method](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
$spanish = array(
    "hello" => "hola",
    "dog" => "perro",
    "car" => "carro"
)

$english = array(
    "hello" => "hello",
    "dog" => "dog",
    "car" => "car"
)

$data = array(
    "sp" => $spanish,
    "en" => $english
)

echo $data['sp']['hello']; //yields 'hola'
echo $data['en']['hello']; //yields 'hello'

$lang = "sp"
$word = "dog";
echo $data[$lang][$word]; //yields 'perro'
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, yes you can. Also you can use UNION to get both result sets in the same iterator.